# Join values from a DataFrame according to an array of indices

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy, rapids, cudf

I have a DataFrame `test` with shape `(1138812, 57)`. The head looks like this:

[image: test.head()]

And I have an array `indices` which has a shape `(1138812, 25)`. It is a 2D array with each subarray having 25 indices. It looks like this:

[[image: loc_data1]

the `indices` array has 25 indices from the DataFrame corresponding to each 1138812 indices from the same DataFrame. I want to create a new DataFrame with 25 X 1138812 rows based on this array. For example:

i have a 2d array, something like:

```py
[[0,2,3],
 [1,0,3],
 [2,1,0],
 [3,1,2]]
```

and i have a pandas dataframe something like:

```
 id   val
0 a    9
1 b    8
2 c    3
3 d    7
```

now i want to get a new dataframe based on the indexes listed in the 2d array, for this example, it will be like:

```
 id   val   id_2  val
0 a    9      a    9
0 a    9      c    3
0 a    9      d    7
1 b    8      b    8
1 b    8      a    9
1 b    9      d    7
2 c    3      c    3
2 c    3      b    8
2 c    3      a    9
3 d    7      d    7
3 d    7      b    8
3 d    7      c    3
```

I tried many approaches including:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = [[0,2,3],
 [1,0,3],
 [2,1,0],
 [3,1,2]]

idse = ['a','b','c','d']
vals = [9,8,3,7]

data = {'id': idse, 'val': vals}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

newdf = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values, len(index[0]), axis=0))

flat_list = [item for sublist in index for item in sublist]
newdf['id_2'] = df.id[flat_list].values
newdf['val_2'] = df.val[flat_list].values
```

and

```py
fdf = pd.DataFrame()
for i, ir in enumerate(l):
  temp_df = df.iloc[ir]
  temp_df['id'] = df.iloc[i]['id']
  temp_df = pd.merge(df,temp_df,how="outer",on="id")
  temp_df = temp_df[temp_df['id']==df.iloc[i]['id']]
  fdf = pd.concat([fdf,temp_df])
fdf
```

both of them work the way I want but they are very very slow for the original DataFrame with 1.1m rows and they take up all the ram which crashes the notebook.
I am using RAPIDS libraries including cuDF, cuPy, cuML which correspond to pandas, numpy/scipy and sklearn respectively and I need a pure numpy/pandas solution so that they can use the GPU cores and make this operation quicker and more efficient.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `df` and `a` the input dataframe and array, you can `repeat` the indices of your dataframe and `concat` it with the dataframes indexed from the flattened array:

```
idx = df.index.repeat(a.shape[1])
df2 = pd.concat(
          [df.loc[idx],
           df.loc[a.ravel()].add_suffix('_2').set_axis(idx)
          ], axis=1)
```

output:

```
  id  val id_2  val_2
0  a    9    a      9
0  a    9    c      3
0  a    9    d      7
1  b    8    b      8
1  b    8    a      9
1  b    8    d      7
2  c    3    c      3
2  c    3    b      8
2  c    3    a      9
3  d    7    d      7
3  d    7    b      8
3  d    7    c      3
```

used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                   'val': [9, 8, 3, 7]})

a = np.array([[0,2,3],
              [1,0,3],
              [2,1,0],
              [3,1,2]])
```

*NB. a quick test shows that is takes 900ms to process 1M rows*

Comment: Thank you so much for this perfect answer, my data took 12 seconds to get processed which is 150x faster than my method, and the ram doesnt get crashed too.

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `assign` with `explode` then `join`

```
out = df.assign(new=a.tolist()).explode('new').set_index('new').add_suffix('_2').join(df)
```

Comment: This answer is as perfect as the other one, so i calculated the time for each of them for my data. This answer took 30 seconds (50x faster than my method) and the ram didnt crash. The other answer took 12 seconds, with nearly the same memory allocation.